# Querying 'across' pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent, pivot

I have two models, beers and distributions, which have a many-to-many relationship. The pivot model `hasMany` kegs, which contain some relevant information to the beer such as pricing and status. When I build my beer index, I need all the information of the beer model, the distributor model, and the keg model. What I am trying to figure out is how to query for all the information in an efficient manner. Here is my current query:

Keg's are scoped on status:

```
public function scopeStatus($query, $status)
{
    return $query->where('status', '=', $status);
}
```

and I build my beers index with:

```
    $kegs = Keg::status($status)->get();
    $beers=[];
    foreach ($kegs as $keg){
        $beer = Beer::find($keg->beer_distribution->beer_id);
        $distributor = Distributor::find($keg->beer_distribution->distributor_id);
        $beers[]=[
        'beer' => $beer,
        'keg' => $keg,
        'distributor' => $distributor];
    }

    return $beers;
```

I know that this is a slow query but im not sure how to do this in a single query. Is there a way that I can run this faster?

Some relevant model code:

```
class Beer extends Eloquent {

    public function distributors()
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Distributor', 'beer_distributions');
    }



class BeerDistribution extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['beer_id', 'distributor_id'];

    public function kegs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Keg', 'beer_distribution_id');
    }



class Distributor extends Eloquent {

  public function beers()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Beer', 'beer_distributions');
  }



class Keg extends Eloquent {

  public function scopeStatus($query, $status)
  {
    return $query->where('status', '=', $status);
  }

  public function beerDistribution()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('BeerDistribution');
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you seen [HasManyThrough](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#has-many-through)?

Comment: Will that work if I have many kegs for each distributor that is connected to the beer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that what I really needed to do was add my query building relations on my Keg model (which was the fatherest 'down' in the nest of relations), and then use eager loading!

I now build my beers index like so:

```
$beers=[];
foreach (Keg::status($status)
    ->with('kegsize', 
        'beerDistribution.beer.brewery',
        'beerDistribution.beer.style', 
        'beerDistribution.distributor')->get() as $keg){
  $beers[]=$keg;
}
return $beers;
```

This brings me down to a stunning total of 10 queries.